# Google Charts - is content drill-down in a chart possible?

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

HighCharts has a really nice drilldown feature: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown - but I'm wondering if it's available in google charts visualization API?  So far as I can tell, it's not possible - but let me describe my idea:

On mouseover, a small pop-out window with additional information about the data is available.  Is it possible to place a link in that?

Because we have these mouseover events on the chart, perhaps it's possible to add a "click" event where we can do whatever we want with it?  In this case, I'd either just have a click send the user to another URL, or possibly force the chart into a new chart animation (basically creating the drill down in this manor).

I'm not too great with jQuery, so I'd appreciate some expertise here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. Although there is no straight way to do it.

I too was looking for this and I figured out a way.

You must prepare a JSON string using PHP (or any other backend language).
PHP should talk to the database recursively and generate the required Javascript literal syntax for every drilldown chart and embed it in a JSON format. Once the JSON string is ready, copy paste the JSON string into your HTML script tag. Add a click event handler to switch to the appropriate Javascript literal. Once the Datatable is ready call chart.draw().

You can have a look at [this](https://rawgit.com/shaw92g/GoogleChartsDrillDown/master/chart.html). Link to [repository](https://github.com/shaw92g/GoogleChartsDrillDown).

Comment: awesome implementation

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this too, and from what i've found, i don't think you can do it from their "dashboard", but i think you can do it either with controls or events on the charts.

The following is an example of using the "group" function on a dataview, so you could use that either on a click event on the chart, or on the click event of a control, and then redraw the chart.
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#group

The trick then would be tracking which filters are currently active and that sort of thing.
It would be nice if this was easily integrated, or even being able to query a dataset/view (as in http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#using_the_query_language)

If you/anyone else knows of an alternative approach i would be interested to hear it..

Answer (score 0):

You may use event handling in Google charts explained here :
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/events

The trick is to use the 'select' event of chart and write your code inside the handler.

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, options);

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'select',selectHandler);

function selectHandler()
{
  //your code here

}
```

You may look at a sample implementation here: https://jsfiddle.net/Abhishek1191/zggv80jo/

Here I have created a combo chart and on click of any data point on line, you will see a pie chart added below the original chart

Comment: how can you store parameters for calling the database, for example I want to catch an ID in order to generate the new graph, If I use handler I can only get the slice text value, is there a way to store ids or other metadata in each slice?